# `puppeteer-page-proxy` with `https` has Error: net::ERR_FAILED or RFC 6066 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, proxy, puppeteer

I use [`puppeteer`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) and [`puppeteer-page-proxy`](https://github.com/Cuadrix/puppeteer-page-proxy/) proxy.

I don't have problem with use `args: ['--proxy-server=socks5://127.0.0.1:9150',...` with either `http` and `https`.

I don't have problem with `useProxy` method and `http` website.

I just have problem with  `useProxy` method and `https` website.

Versions:

```
node v17.2.0
Chromium Version 101.0.4950.0 (Developer Build) (64-bit)
+-- puppeteer-page-proxy@1.2.8
+-- puppeteer@13.6.0
```

Sample code:

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
import useProxy from 'puppeteer-page-proxy';

let options = {
    headless: false,
    devtools: true,
};
const browser = await puppeteer.launch(options);
const page = await browser.newPage();

await useProxy(page, 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9150');
await page.goto('https://api.ipify.org/');
var result = await page.content();
console.log(result);
```

Errors:

```js
C:\>node test_proxy.mjs
(node:15152) [DEP0123] DeprecationWarning: Setting the TLS ServerName to an IP address is not permitted by RFC 6066. This will be ignored in a future version.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
C:\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\FrameManager.js:156
                    ? new Error(`${response.errorText} at ${url}`)
                      ^

Error: net::ERR_FAILED at https://api.ipify.org/
    at navigate (C:\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\FrameManager.js:156:23)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async FrameManager.navigateFrame (C:\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\FrameManager.js:131:21)
    at async Frame.goto (C:\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\FrameManager.js:512:16)
    at async Page.goto (C:\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Page.js:1167:16)
    at async file:///C:/test_proxy.mjs:38:2

Node.js v17.2.0

C:\>node --trace-deprecation test_proxy.mjs
(node:5776) [DEP0123] DeprecationWarning: Setting the TLS ServerName to an IP address is not permitted by RFC 6066. This will be ignored in a future version.
    at Object.connect (node:_tls_wrap:1669:15)
    at SocksProxyAgent.<anonymous> (C:\node_modules\puppeteer-page-proxy\node_modules\socks-proxy-agent\dist\agent.js:162:38)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (C:\node_modules\puppeteer-page-proxy\node_modules\socks-proxy-agent\dist\agent.js:5:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
C:\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\FrameManager.js:156
                    ? new Error(`${response.errorText} at ${url}`)
                      ^

Error: net::ERR_FAILED at https://api.ipify.org/
    at navigate (C:\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\FrameManager.js:156:23)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async FrameManager.navigateFrame (C:\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\FrameManager.js:131:21)
    at async Frame.goto (C:\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\FrameManager.js:512:16)
    at async Page.goto (C:\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Page.js:1167:16)
    at async file:///C:/test_proxy.mjs:38:2

Node.js v17.2.0
```

As stated in the error message about RFC 6066, I searched and found this: 
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6066 
But I do not know exactly what that means.

Also when I used `await useProxy(page, 'socks5://localhost:9150');` or domain name, get another error:

```js
C:\>node test_proxy.mjs
C:\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\FrameManager.js:156
                    ? new Error(`${response.errorText} at ${url}`)
                      ^

Error: net::ERR_FAILED at https://api.ipify.org/
    at navigate (C:\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\FrameManager.js:156:23)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async FrameManager.navigateFrame (C:\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\FrameManager.js:131:21)
    at async Frame.goto (C:\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\FrameManager.js:512:16)
    at async Page.goto (C:\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Page.js:1167:16)
    at async Timeout._onTimeout (file:///C:/test_proxy.mjs:47:3)

Node.js v17.2.0
```